# C programming with pointers

Tags: arrays, pointers, generics

Write a program that creates a random array of 20 integers with a pointer that initially points to the first element of the array.  The program will have a while loop that allows the user to do any of the following:

- print the array of numbers with the pointed to number highlighted in some way
- move the pointer left or right a certain number of items in the array
- change the value of the pointed to number
- quit the program

All the changes to the list of numbers must be done with pointers (not by referencing the array index),

I have this to start off which is just setting up the array

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main{
int array[20];
for(int i=0; I<20;i++){
array[I]=rand() % 100;
}
int pointer=&array[0];
int i=0;


return 0;
}
```

I would really appreciate the help

Comment: Questions asking for homework help must include a summary of the work you've done so far to solve the problem, and a description of the difficulty you are having solving it. Please read [How to ask homework questions](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334822) and [edit] your post. If you can't get started, ask your instructor for help. You'll find your experiences here will be much better if you spend some time taking the [tour] and reading the [help] pages to learn how the site works before you begin posting, as was suggested when you created your account.

Comment: Your edit didn't help. The code you've posted won't compile, which means it can't ever execute.

Answer (score 0):

**"with a pointer that points to the first element of the array"**

Basically means you need to dynamically allocate memory. A memory block that is allocated always return a pointer to the first element of the array:

```
int* array = calloc(sizeof(int)*20);
// Allocate memory for 20 integers ^
```

Now you have an array of 20 integers and `array` points to it's first element. Then, if we don't actually want to reference the index.

```
*(arr+1)
```

Will give you the value of the second element since it evaluates to `arr[1]`.

To print them using a while loop, use an integer to keep track of the current index and `while(array+index)` print it and increment index.
This is so because memory of a computer is like a street with different houses with an integral number along it.